# swift how to change `CGRect(x: 400, y:500` to a stored variable

Tags: swift, cgrect

I'm righting a function to animate something I'm passing it a UIImageView  (I shall be passing it the x and y  once I sort this bit out)
how do I change the `CGRect(x: 400, y:500`

if I change `CGRect(x: 400, y:500`  to `CGRect(x: xdis, y:ydis` 
I get build fail extra argument "width" in call
but works fine as it is

```
    func UpAndDown(thingToAnimate:UIImageView)
  {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        let xdis = 30
        let ydis = 20
        thingToAnimate.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y:500 , width: thingToAnimate.frame.width, height: thingToAnimate.frame.height)

    }, completion: { finished in
        println("we moved")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because `xdis` and `ydis` are of type `Int`, whereas `CGRect` requires type `CGFloat` as parameters. Therefore, you need to make `xdis` and `ydis` of type `CGFloat` like so:

```
let xdis: CGFloat = 30
```

Comment: hi thanks that sorted it  id tried doubles didn't think of a float now I've got to look at passing the cgfloats at the same time thanks again